# HTC Alarm Volume after update to 7.8

Tags: 7.8, volume

I just upgraded my HTC Arrive to WP 7.8 and now the alarm is like 50% volume even when the ringer volume is 100%. Is there a way to turn this up? I use my alarm to wake up by and it's so quiet I'm afraid it won't wake me.

Comment: You have two questions here. I have removed the second question. Please post it as a separate question (you can view the edit history and copy+paste).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the alarm sound.

1. Open **Alarms**
2. Choose your alarm
3. Tap **Sound** and choose a louder sound.